# Simple regular expression to get text between <br/> and next <br/>

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string that contains this (and another things):

```
<b>SINOPSIS:</b><br/> 
Text text text and mooore text...<br/>
```

I need a reg-ex to get the text between those first two `<br/>` tags.

Thanks...

Note: There are more `<br/>` tags. I need the first occurrence only..

I will be using PHPs preg_match() function.

Comment: What regex engine will you be using?

Comment: I will be using PHPs preg_match() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work, make sure to enable multiline

there are other fancier ways with more checks ect...

edit:

```
preg_match('!\<br\/\>.+?\<br\/\>!s', $string);
```

Example 2 (For whitespace before close `br`),

```
!\<br\s*/?>.+?\<br\s*/?>!s
```

Comment: Not working. its getting the second pairs of br tags... Or maybe is a multi line problem. How to enable multi line?

Comment: it shouldn't be, can you post more of what you're matching against? as it should be limiting to the FIRST <br/> and second then stop.

Comment: Like I said, its maybe a multi line problem. How to enable multi line?

Comment: my bad I put the wrong option in I edited my answer try that one

Comment: final version is there in case it helps, I removed the allowance for whitespaces in the <br /> if you want those it can be done just more complicated

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to point you to this brilliant answer by bobince that I stumbled upon when I was tempted to ask a similar question: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)